# Add ajax handler on razor page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am familiar with the traditional `MyPage.cshtml` and `MyPage.cshtml.cs` files with `OnGetAsync` and `OnPostAsync` methods, but how do I add another handler to the model page that I can call with javascript without doing a full form post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Pages;

public class ListModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiForgery;

    public AntiforgeryTokenSet AntiForgeryToken {get; private set;}

    public ListModel(
        IAntiforgery antiForgery
    )
    {
        this._antiForgery = antiForgery;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        AntiForgeryToken = _antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostWafflesAsync(bool test)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Test approval result="+test);
        return new JsonResult(new {
            received = true,
            test,
        });
    }
}
```

```
<script>
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', false);
fetch(
    `${window.location}?handler=Waffles`,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken:`@Model.AntiForgeryToken.RequestToken`,
        },
        body: formData,
});
</script>
```

In this case, we return a JsonResult to be more easily consumable by the javascript (but this example does nothing with the result).

Note that the handler referenced in the javascript is `Waffles` instead of `OnPostWafflesAsync`, [related](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8998)

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-6.0#multiple-handlers-per-page